# How to store UUID as int

Tags: objective-c, uuid

I'm having some issues here. I am using the following code to generate the UUID in my application.

```
- (NSString *)GetUUID {
    CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
    CFRelease(theUUID);
    return [(NSString *)string autorelease];
}
```

This code returns an `NSString` object back. Now I want to store the generated `UUID` as `unsigned int`. Any suggestions on how can I do it here?

Comment: You can't store a `UUID` as an `unsigned int`. The former is 128 bits wide, the latter is only 32 bits wide on the iPhone. It just won't fit. If you share more about why you'd want to do this, we might be able to help.

Comment: I want to store the uuid as in numeric form. Something like an integer not a string. As it takes too much time to search and compare in string form. Is it possible..

Comment: No, it's not possible. And a GUID is already numeric - just don't convert it to a string.

Comment: ahaan okey.. so can i store GUID in any type or i have to use it like that straight away..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), UUIDs are 128 bits long.  The largest int value you'll be able to work with is 64 bits.  Therefore, I'd says you can't store it in an int because there simply isn't room.

Comment: String is taking too much time in searching and comparing on mine server. Is it possible to adapt to any other type..

Comment: I believe it is.  You could create a struct that contained parts of the UUID, and then write comparison functions to work with them.  Still, it depends on exactly what you are trying to do.  Your post is tagged iPhone, but you're talking about a server.  How are you comparing them?

Comment: I was using a NSString to generate UUIDs on an iphone and saving them in a database then uploading them to the server. If i have to get that data back i send the related UUID from the phone. It was taking time so i opted for int but still i think i will go with NSString..

Comment: Wait, scratch what I just said.  I just read Michael's comment.  If you look at the documentation for CFUUID, it says that it's stored as an array of bytes.  So you don't really need to create your own struct to represent it.

Comment: I would say then use CFUUID to represent UUIDs in your iPhone application, and then in the database find a good way to store the UUID as 16 bytes.

Comment: okey scratched...
now i have created the UUID if i use the GetUUID i will be getting parts of it ..?

Comment: Okay, take a look at the documentation for CFUUID: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html.  In here you can see that  you can use `CFUUIDCreate` to create a UUID.  You can also create one with an array of bytes using `CFUUIDCreateWithBytes`.  That would be useful if you were retrieving a UUID from your server.    and needed an `CFUUID` representation of it on the iPhone.

Answer (score 6):

Convert UUID to String using `.UUIDString`

Take string's `.hash` property.

Cast to int.

`int numericFormUUID = (int)UUIDString.hash;`

---

Note: collision is possible, as always, with hashing. Two users could end up with the same value here, whereas UUID is guaranteed unique.

Comment: Another neat way would be to SHA256 the UID so that you get a hex string, then convert hex to decimal. You can truncate as needed to fit your byte-requirements.

Comment: @MichaelCole Can you elaborate?

Comment: @MichaelCole >`No. Google it or understand your code before posting`. Ok Mr Pompous. I hashed the UUID so that it would be within range of `int` as OP asked (128 bits -> 64 bits). I also added a footnote that hashing is lossy and collision is therefore possible. What exactly have I misunderstood?

Answer (score -1):

There's a new `.hashValue` property.

```
UUID().hashValue
```

Comment: And how are you going to recreate the original UUID from the hash value later on?